# How to install patchutils on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, interdiff

I already have Git and Git Bash installed. I find it inconvenient to create an "interdiff" between two patch files in Git Bash using only git commands. I would like to install patchutils, so that I can use the `interdiff` command -- and thus create interdiffs using the patch files directly, without committing code first.

How do I install patchutils such that I can use it from Git Bash? I tried `npm install patchutils`, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this issue would be to use MSYS2 instead of "Git Bash".
MSYS2 has its own Git package, and it has a PatchUtils package:

https://packages.msys2.org/base/patchutils